# image isn't displaying from database which is in longblob type

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
 <div class="form-group">
        <label for="image">image:</label>
        <input type="file" name="img" id="img" placeholder="upload image" class="form-control" required>
     </div>
//for upload
     <?php
     if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $user_vid=$_POST['voterid'];
        $filename = addslashes($_FILES['img']['name']);
        $tmpname = addslashes($_FILES['img']['tmp_name']);
        $filetype = addslashes($_FILES['img']['type']);
        $array = array('jpg','jpeg');
        $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        if(!empty($filename)){
            if(in_array($ext, $array)){
                $upload="insert into image (voter_id,name,image) values ('$user_vid','$filename','$tmpname')";
                $up=$conn->query($upload);
                if($up)
                {
                $accountSuccess="<p class='text text-center text-success'>Image uploaded</p>";
                }
                else
                {
                echo "error";
                }  
            } else {
            echo "unsupported format";
            }
        } else {
            echo "please insert the image";
        }
    }
    ?>

//for display
    <?php 
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $search=$_POST['voterid'];
        $show = "select * from image where voter_id='$search'";
        $sh=$conn->query($show);
        if($sh->num_rows>0){
            while($row=$sh->fetch_array()){


                        echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($row['image']).'"width="450" height="220>"';
         }
        }
    }
    ?>
```

image is uploaded to databse but **problem is image isn't displaying. showing an image with corrupted file logo in the top**. I've used type: Longblob in database to image. Please help me with this.

And when i opened the image it says >the image "data:image/jpeg;base
,QZ.........w" cannot be displayed becasue it contains errors.

Comment: `'"width="450"` needs to be `'" width="450"`

Answer (score 0):

Your height and width attributes are not mentioned correctly in the `img` tag

**Change them to**

```
 echo '<img src= data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($row['image']).'width= 450 height= 220>';
         }
```

Comment: I just removed both the styles i.e., height and width but same error!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <?php 
                $file_path = "#";
                $hide_img = 'style="display:none"';
                if(!empty($u->image_name))
                {
                $hide_img = "";
                    $file_path = url('/') .'/'.$u->image_path.'/'.$u->image_name;
                }  ?>
                <img id="blah" src="{{ $file_path }}" width="300px" height="auto">
            </div>                                            
            </div>
        </div>
```

In this code variable u have all the details from database table.

Answer (score -1):

### Tyr this

```
$valid_exts = array('docx', 'jpg', 'doc', 'pdf', 'png');
$ext = strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES['img']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
if(isset($_FILES['img']['name']))
    {

        if(in_array($ext, $valid_exts))
        {
            $uid = uniqid();
            $fpath = 'uploads/'.$uid.'.'.$ext;
            $upstatus = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'],$fpath);
            $image = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $fpath);
        }
        else
        {
            echo json_encode(array("status"=>'error', "error"=>'Invalid File'));
            exit();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $image = '';
    }
```

<-- Display Image --!>

```
<html>
<body>
<?php 
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $search=$_POST['voterid'];
        $show = "select * from image where voter_id='$search'";
        $sh=$conn->query($show);
        if($sh->num_rows>0){
            while($row=$sh->fetch_array()){
                  echo '<img src="<?php echo $row['image']; ?>" />';
         }
        }
    }
</body>
</html>
```